# Predicting the winner of a contest

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis

This is just a general question, but I ran into a few situations lately with this same framework and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Suppose we have 100 contests worth of data each with 8 individuals in it.  There is just 1 individual in each of the 100 contests that can win.   Suppose, I have a number of variables for each individual.   What statistical tool can I use to predict the likelihood that a particular individual would win the contest?

I first thought this would be a simple logistic regression, but the fact that each row in the data set is not independent (if individual C wins, then the other 7 cannot win) seems to suggest that may not be the best tool to use here.

It effectively would be P(A wins | A has these variables and is playing against B, C, D, E, and F each with these variables).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try multinomial logistic regression where Y is the winner A-F and X are the variables for each individual: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Comment: Would I just have 100 cases for the 100 contests?   Randomize the order of A through F on each case, so that Y contains all options A through F?